# Can I load persistence XML in JPA Hibernate, outside the package

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I want to place my `persistence.XML` (of JPA hibernate) outside the package, somewhere else in the disk, so that my program can load the XML (which is not placed in resources folder but somewhere outside the package) and can form a database connection.

I used:

```
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  try {
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("path"));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

But this also not solving the problem.
Got an error as:

> aug 12, 2018 12:28:24 EM org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser doResolve
>       INFO: HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath

I don't want compiler should find the XML in this path, I want to load from other paths.

Any leads appreciated!

Comment: Would [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773258/how-to-modify-properties-after-create-entity-manager-factory-from-persistence-xm) work for you? You would still need to create a `persistence.xml` in the resources folder, but you could then override most of the properties

Comment: Is your question what @crizzis posted? The persistence.xml must be in the META-INF folder in the class path. Is your application running standalone or in a app server?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Hi,thanks for the reply, my question is different from what crizzis asked. Currently my persistence.xml is in META-INF and my application is running on server and in my server I can only upload the jar file so my persistence.xml is not being loaded. That is why wanted to ask like is there any way to load the persistence.xml from any other path ?

Comment: What kind of server? And why is the Persistence.xml not in jar?